# ¿Como puedo agrupar iteradores de pandas, para analizar un mismo dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe, con información de distancia, por lo que lo ordene por distancia, y por SITIO, por lo que lo agrupe por SITIO.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es ya teniendo agrupado y ordenado el DF, sacar por cada SITIO las filas mas cercanas con datos de HOGARES hasta que se cumpla LA CAPACIDAD del SITIO, ya que ya tengo agrupado por sitio, pensaba iterar los grupos hasta tener las filas que me cumplan esa capacidad.
Estos son los datos con los que trabajo, la data tienes mas datos pero no son relevantes para el proceso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La finalidad de hacerlo grupo por grupo es que al final concatene estas filas en un solo dataframe.

Este es el codigo que utilice para organizar el dataframe

```
''''

    sitios = df[['OID_','NOMBRE_OFI']]'
    sitios.drop_duplicates(subset ="NOMBRE_OFI")
    orddist = df.sort_values('NEAR_DIST')
    agrup = orddist.groupby(orddist.NOMBRE_OFI)
    resultado = pd.DataFrame(columns=['OID_', 'Departamento', 'Municipio', 'Localidad', 'Barrio',
           'EstratoMod', 'CantHogares', 'CantPersonas', 'Latitud', 'Longitud',
           'Regional_ori', 'Ciudad_ori', 'NOMBRE_OFI', 'Capacidad_HHPP',
           'Cap_HHPP_80', 'No__OLT_ori', 'NEAR_DIST'])
    consulta = pd.DataFrame(columns=['OID_', 'Departamento', 'Municipio', 'Localidad', 'Barrio',
           'EstratoMod', 'CantHogares', 'CantPersonas', 'Latitud', 'Longitud',
           'Regional_ori', 'Ciudad_ori', 'NOMBRE_OFI', 'Capacidad_HHPP',
           'Cap_HHPP_80', 'No__OLT_ori', 'NEAR_DIST'])
    ''''
```

Soy primerizo manejando programando y manipulando datos con pandas, he visto que anidar ciclos no es lo mas recomendable, pero no se que funciones de pandas me ayuden con el requerimiento.

```
''''
    for i in sitios.index:
    consulta = agrup.get_group(sitios['NOMBRE_OFI'][i] )
    count_row = consulta.shape[0]
    suma = 0
    consulta.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    for x in consulta.index:
            if (consulta['Capacidad_HHPP'][x] < suma):
                suma = consulta['CantHogares'][x] + suma
            else:
                count_row = x
                count_row = math.trunc(count_row)
                consulta = consulta.iloc[:count_row,:]
                resultado = pd.concat([resultado,consulta],ignore_index=True)
''''
```

Este fue el código que desarrolle, ambos ciclos hacen su trabajo correctamente, lo estoy trabajando en un jupyter notebook, el ciclo inicial debe iterar por 147 Sitios distintos, y el segundo tomar las filas del DF principal que cumplan la condicion y agruparlas en un solo DF.

Pero al ejecutar los ciclos anidados que es lo que necesito, me salta error.

''''

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\IC4182A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py:391, in RangeIndex.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    390 try:
--> 391     return self._range.index(new_key)
    392 except ValueError as err:

ValueError: 1 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 7
      5 consulta.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
      6 for x in consulta.index:
----> 7     if (consulta['Capacidad_HHPP'][x] < suma):
      8         suma = consulta['CantHogares'][x] + suma
      9     else:

File c:\Users\IC4182A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:981, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
    978     return self._values[key]
    980 elif key_is_scalar:
--> 981     return self._get_value(key)
    983 if is_hashable(key):
    984     # Otherwise index.get_value will raise InvalidIndexError
...
--> 393         raise KeyError(key) from err
    394 self._check_indexing_error(key)
    395 raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 1
```

''''

si me aconsejan una manera mas optima de realizarlo, o el por que no me corre los ciclos anidados lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Buen día, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` y el mínimo código necesario para reproducir tu problema, así como un ejemplo del resultado deseado.

Comment: Ya quedo, no se si necesitan algo mas, es mi primer post